# Insert missing rows in table b and update table a

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables: `user_account` and `email_validation`.
`user_account` has `user_id`, `email` and `email_validation_id`.
`email_validation` has `email_validation_id`, `user_account_id`, and `email`.

In normal and correct way, for each user in `user_account` (for example `[user_id="123", email="user@domain.com", email_validation_id="456"]`) there is a row in `email_validation` (for example `[email_validation_id="456", user_account_id="123", email="user@domain.com"]`).

But, some things got wrong and now I have users with no email validation. So, I would like to add rows manually: for each user from `user_account` *which don’t have a row* in `email_validation` (i.e. no row with it’s `user_id`) insert `[email_validation_id=<The current max of (email_validation.email_validation_id) + 1>, user_account_id=<user_account.user_id>, email=<user_account.email>]` and update the `user_account.email_validation_id` to `<email_validation.email_validation_id>`.

I have no idea how to approach this :\

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

If I had understood everything correctly this could help.

### Missing email validation

To create/insert missing email validation you can do.

```
INSERT INTO email_validation(user_account_id, email)
SELECT user_id, email
FROM user_account WHERE email_validation_id is null;
```

### Auto increase the id

To auto increase the id you can do.

**Table definition:**

```
CREATE TABLE tablename
(
  id NUMBER(10)
);

ALTER TABLE tablename ADD (CONSTRAINT tbn_pk PRIMARY KEY (id));
CREATE SEQUENCE tbn_seq START WITH 1;
```

Or you can use `Identity` Columns is available from Oracle 12c+.

```
CREATE TABLE tablename
(
   id NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
);
```

**Trigger definition:**

```
CREATE SEQUENCE tbn_seq START WITH 1;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tbn_id_insert BEFORE INSERT ON departments 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SELECT tbn_seq.NEXTVAL
    INTO :new.id
    FROM dual;
END;
/
```

### Update the user_account

To update the user_account.email_validation_id you can do.

```
DECLARE
    v_email_validation_id user_account.email_validation_id%TYPE;
BEGIN
    FOR user_account_rec IN (SELECT * FROM user_account WHERE email_validation_id is NULL)
    LOOP
        SELECT email_validation_id
        INTO v_email_validation_id
        FROM email_validation
        WHERE user_account_id = user_account_rec.user_id;

        UPDATE user_account
        SET email_validation_id = v_email_validation_id
        where user_id = user_account_rec.user_id;
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

I hope I was able to help you.

Comment: I don't want you to think this answer went unnoticed! I'll resume work only on Monday. Thanks!!

Comment: You are a polite person. Have a nice weekend.